# 'go get' unexpected behavior on docker container

Tags: docker, go, go-get

I'm having an unexpected behavior when running `go get [module]` inside a docker container compared to my local machine and I will appreciate any help to understand the reason for this different behavior.

## 1) Local machine

### Command:

```
go get github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
```

### Result:

- ***$GOPATH**/bin* contains executable `gocov`.
- The module was downloaded into ***$GOPATH**/src/github.com/axw/gocov/gocov*.
- ***$GOPATH**/pkg* doesn't contains anything related to `gocov` package.

## 2) Docker container

### Dockerfile:

This dockerfile is for testing purposes, because of that it doesn't have an entrypoint.

```
FROM golang:alpine

COPY .  /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN go get -v -u github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
RUN ls $GOPATH/bin
RUN ls -laR / | grep "^\/.*gocov.*$"
```

### Result:

- ***$GOPATH**/bin* contains executable `gocov`.
- ***$GOPATH**/src* doesn't contains anything related to `gocov` package.
- The module was downloaded into ***$GOPATH**/pkg/mod/github.com/axw/gocov@v1.0.0*.

Comment: That is the expected result. GOPATH is not used for module source.

Comment: You might as well update start working with modules now, as `go get` is being deprecated as a method for building main packages. See https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command on the changes to `go install` and `go get`. If you want the project source, checkout the project with `git`.

Answer (score 0):

From the date your posting this I take that you are running go >= 1.16.0 inside Docker which introduced some changes to the module system (like @JimB commented: *See [golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command) on the changes to go install and go get*). You are probably running an older version of go on your machine.

You can verify this by using following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.15
COPY .  /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN go get -v -u github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
RUN ls $GOPATH/bin
RUN ls -laR / | grep "^\/.*gocov.*$"
```

This will create an image containing the code inside `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this.